# How do you use url params for creating a link_to when belongs_to and has_many associations are at play?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a very simple concept that, even after completing several tutorials, now that I'm "on my own", I can't seem to get the routes/controllers set up properly to return what I'm needing.

The user is presented with a list of states and, upon clicking a state, I want him/her to be taken to a list of counties for that state.

I have models for State and County.

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :counties

class County < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
```

Relevant parts of the schema

States:

```
create_table "states", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "abbreviation"
  ...
```

Counties:

```
create_table "counties", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "state_id"
  ...
```

In my routes, to represent the association, I have nested the following

```
resources :states, shallow: true do
  resources :counties do
    ...
```

This seems to be the pertinent portion form rails routes

```
state_counties  GET  /states/:state_id/counties(.:format)  counties#index
```

The controller files are currently the standard CRUD actions that come with scaffolds.  I've modified the Counties index action to mirror what I use in the console to pull up the needed counties

```
class CountiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @counties = County.where(state_id: params[:id])
  end
```

In the index.html.erb file for States I'm trying to iterate through the states and provide a link that takes the user to a separate page listing that state's counties and this is where I'm at a loss.

```
<% states.each do |state| %>
  <%= link_to ... ??? %>
```

I've tried many different things and I can't get it to take.

When I hard-type the url as say states/3/counties the page renders, but it's blank and no counties are shown even though the log window shows controller: counties, action: index, state_id: '3'.

My thinking so far is that it needs to be a link that refers to the Counties controller and somehow uses the id param for the state that's clicked on... I've scoured through a bunch of different posts, but if there is an answer for this already out there that I missed, please don't hesitate to share it!

Thank you in advance for your help, let me know if I need to post more code snippets. In the meantime, I'll keep digging and update if I come across anything that works.

Comment: For us zipcode & counties , use https://github.com/ChakreshwarSharma/us_zipcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to index page you should pass `state` as path attribute:

```
<%= link_to 'name', state_counties_path(state) %>
```

`rake routes` says that `state_counties` route is `/states/:state_id/counties(.:format)`. It means that `state.id` is `params[:state_id]` in counties controller. Change index method in controller to:

```
@counties = County.where(state_id: params[:state_id])
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight idej, not only did that fix the problem, your explanation helps me understand how to interpret the rails routes listings!  *two thumbs up*